# Is there a list of all municipal government forms in a machine readable format?

Tags: usa, government

I've found a list of government forms at the US federal level by looking at the [OIRA PRA Information Collections XML file](http://www.reginfo.gov/public/do/PRAXML). Is there a list of similar forms at the state/local level for the US?

Comment: I suppose you are looking for US specifically?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the omission.

Comment: At the *municipal* level?  There are 27 municipalities in my county alone ... and we don't even have a machine-readable master list for my town.  (I don't even know that we have that list at all ... we've spent the last 6 years that I've been a Town Commissioner trying to get much of our documentation standardized & in digital form)

Comment: And when I saw the question, I thought you were looking for something like the [NLC categories](http://www.nlc.org/build-skills-and-networks/resources/cities-101/city-structures/forms-of-municipal-government) ... my town is 'Council-Manager' by that scheme, but '[Strong Mayor](http://www.mdmunicipal.org/index.aspx?NID=417)' by MML's classifications, even though our mayor isn't elected separately (it's a decision of the board, non-rotating for the 2 year term).

Answer (score 8):

Probably not.

There is definitely no such list for Washington, DC (Government of the District of Columbia).

There was forms automation project back in 2006/2007 where some forms where converted to database backend using LiquidOffice tool. You can see list of all currently published forms for DC.gov here http://forms.dc.gov/index.html (click Forms on the left). But beware, there are plenty of forms that are just stan alone PDFs or custom webpages.

Comment: I would certainly believe this would be the case as states/localities tend to like to choose their own reports.

Answer (score 2):

While surely not as comprehensive as what you're looking for, the Open311 GeoReport API standard does cover a wide range of forms for service request transactions with city governments. Currently, this is primarily focused on location specific things in public space, like a form to request that a broken streetlight gets repaired, but some Open311 APIs are also starting to include location-agnostic forms that are more targeted at the needs of an individual. Since the Open311 API allows for a lot of flexibility in publishing and receiving custom forms it may get even wider use as a standard way to make this available in a machine readable format. You can see a list of city Open311 endpoints at http://wiki.open311.org/GeoReport_v2/Servers and an aggregate list of the forms that are managed by these APIs at https://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/open311_services/